# Add external handler for onlick event to SVG element

Tags: javascript, html, svg

I trying to add JS handler to some my SVG's children. I using following code inside SVG:

```
  <script type="text/javascript" id="script3079">
    addClickEvents();

    function addClickEvents() {
        var keys = document.getElementsByTagName('path');
        for (var i=0; i &lt; keys.length; i++){
            keys[i].addEventListener('click', keyClicked);
        }
    }

    function keyClicked(e) {
        var node = e.target;
        alert(node.id);
    }
  </script>
```

And it is working ok. But now I want to call function from EXTERNAL javascript file:

```
//myfile.js
function keyClickedExternal(e) {
  alert('keyClickedExternal');
}
```

Of course it is attached to my HTML via `script` tag.

I tried following bindings:

```
keys[i].addEventListener('click', keyClickedExternal); //keyClickedExternal undefined
keys[i].addEventListener('click', parent.keyClickedExternal); //keyClickedExternal undefined
keys[i].addEventListener('click', top.keyClickedExternal); //keyClickedExternal undefined
keys[i].addEventListener('click', parent.keyClickedExternal); //keyClickedExternal undefined
```

I checked DOM:

```
parent.window.document //access violation
window.document //refers to SVG document
document //the same as previous
```

Finally, I do not understand how to bind external handler to SVG child.

Comment: Are your svgs and js files served from the same domain? You might want to check http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy

Comment: Yes. Moreover, right now I running it without any webserver, just as files from my computer (using file:/// link)

Comment: You're on Chrome right? It treats different local files as different domains. You need to use a webserver or a different UA.

Comment: @RobertLongson you're right! It is strange, but when I opened file using webserver `parent.keyClickedExternal` and `top.keyClickedExternal` resolved right!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Robert Longson said problem was related to Chrome's security - it is treating other local file as different domain. Use the webserver, Luk.

Answer (score 0):

You should add `document.domain = 'Your_domain_name';`
at the beginning line of each JavaScript files, I also recommend reading about crossdomain.xml file about running scripts from different domain names (eg: statics.yourdomain.com including static css, js, img files)

P.S: Sorry for late reply, I was looking for something else and saw that your question remained non-replied